# xslt 2.0 xsl:number recursive counter - more efficient way?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to populate all attribute/value elements whose name is "order" with an increasing counter value.

```
...
<attribute>
    <name>order</name>
    <value></value>
</attribute>
...
```

The "order" attributes can appear anywhere in the document and at any depth. The order value does not need to be exactly accurate, but each order attribute lower in the document must have a higher value than all preceding order attributes.

I'm using multi-pass processing. The first pass generates the content, and the second pass populates the value tag with the counter value. The counting code looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="postprocess">   
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="postprocess" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[self::n:value and parent::n:attribute[n:name = 'order']]" mode="postprocess">        
    <value>
        <xsl:number level="any" count="*"/>
    </value>
</xsl:template>
```

This works but does not seem very performant. I'm working on relatively large files - around 20MB - and the counting code above adds about 50% to my processing time.

I found a similar question here:
[high-performance alternative to xsl:number](https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/567459-high-performance-alternative-xsl-number) 
but no good answers for me.

Is there a better way?

I'm using Saxon HE 9.7.0.

Comment: The usual way to write the match pattern would be `match="n:attribute[n:name = 'order']/n:value"`. Whether that improves performance will depend on the processor used and has to be tested. The `count="*` astonishes me, it doesn't seem to match your verbal description, it seems you want `count="n:attribute[n:name = 'order']/n:value"`. Again to judge the performance you will have to test with a particular version of a particular processor.

Comment: The performance of xsl:number is going to vary greatly from one XSLT processor to another, because it's very amenable to smart optimization (the naive algorithm described in the spec will certainly be slow). So a question about performance really needs to say which processor you are using.

Comment: Using accumulators in XSLT 3.0 may be faster (in fact recent Saxon releases implement some `xsl:number` instructions using accumulators internally). On the other hand, it may not: a naive implementation of accumulators will be just as slow as a naive implementation of `xsl:number`.

Comment: I had used `count="*"` because I didn't care about an exact count of the order attributes, just that the order value was always increasing. It does make a huge difference to use just `count="n:attribute[n:name = 'order']/n:value"`. Thanks!

Comment: @Martin - I think your improved count pattern is really the answer to my question (since Tim C's alternate approach is equivalent performance-wise when using the same patterns). Do you want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite or change both the template's match pattern as well as the count pattern to try whether that improves performance:

```
<xsl:template match="n:attribute[n:name = 'order']/n:value" mode="postprocess">        
    <value>
        <xsl:number level="any" count="n:attribute[n:name = 'order']/n:value"/>
    </value>
</xsl:template>
```

Your comment suggests that those changes improved performance for you so I post this as an answer.

Comment: This simple change to the count pattern eliminated virtually all of the 50% processing time increase from the counting code. The change to the match pattern did not make a performance impact but is cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate way, although I have no idea if it improves performance or not.

First, create a variable that can effectively be used to map the `value` elements to their position

```
<xsl:variable name="attributes">
    <xsl:for-each select="//n:attribute[n:name = 'order']/n:value">
        <n:value key="{generate-id()}" pos="{position()}" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then, create a key to lookup these values

```
<xsl:key name="attributes" match="n:value" use="@key" />
```

Then, instead of using `xsl:number`, get the position like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('attributes', generate-id(), $attributes)/@pos" />
```

For example, given this XML

```
<root xmlns="n">
<attribute>
    <name>order</name>
    <value></value>
</attribute>
<attribute>
    <name>order</name>
    <value></value>
</attribute>
<children>
    <attribute>
        <name>order</name>
        <value></value>
    </attribute>
</children>
</root>
```

And this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:n="n" exclude-result-prefixes="n">

<xsl:key name="attributes" match="n:value" use="@key" />

<xsl:variable name="attributes">
    <xsl:for-each select="//n:attribute[n:name = 'order']/n:value">
        <n:value key="{generate-id()}" pos="{position()}" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">   
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="n:attribute[n:name = 'order']/n:value">
    <value xmlns="n">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('attributes', generate-id(), $attributes)/@pos" />
    </value>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is this:

```
<attribute>
    <name>order</name>
    <value>1</value>
</attribute>
<attribute>
    <name>order</name>
    <value>2</value>
</attribute>
<children>
    <attribute>
        <name>order</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </attribute>
</children>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternate approach. Using Saxon HE 9.7.0 on my particular xml data the performance of your approach is spot on with using the xsl:number approach with Martin Honnen's improved match and count patterns above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code may it will help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="n"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="value[../name = 'order']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::value[../name = 'order'])+1"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There's no reason to believe this will be faster than using xsl:number; in fact it's much harder for the processor to optimize. But it all depends which XSLT processor you are using.